# How can I pass the filename from a variable locally into ssh?

Tags: shell, variables, if-statement, ssh, sh

I am checking whether a file exists on a remote server but instead of hardcoding the filename I want to pass in a variable. Is this not possible this way? Should I take an alternative route?

**Works:**

```
if ssh "$SSH_USER"@"$SSH_IP_ADDRESS" "echo $OUTPUT1 && cd $SSH_LOC && pwd && echo $SSH_LOC && [ -f live_29-06-2018.txt ];"
    then
        echo "This file exists."
    else
        echo "This file doesn't exist."
    fi
```

Displays *"This file exists."*

**Doesn't work:**

```
if ssh "$SSH_USER"@"$SSH_IP_ADDRESS" "echo $OUTPUT1 && cd $SSH_LOC && pwd && echo $SSH_LOC && [ -f $OUTPUT1 ];"
then
    echo "This file exists."
else
    echo "This file doesn't exist."
fi
```

Displays *"This file doesn't exist."*

Comment: The code here has serious security vulnerabilities -- if you had `OUTPUT1='$(rm -rf ~)'`, this would be not `echo`ed but executed, deleting files on the remote machine. In general, you *shouldn't ever* use string concatenation (as this does) to generate code which will later be parsed by a shell, except when using an escaping mechanism in conjunction.

Comment: Compare to `printf -v ssh_cmd 'set -x; echo %q && cd %q && pwd && echo %q && [ -f %q ]' "$OUTPUT1" "$SSH_LOC" "$SSH_LOC" "$OUTPUT1"; ssh remote-host "$ssh_cmd"`, which ensures that all content is escaped before being passed over the wire.

Comment: BTW, note that all-caps variable names are defined by POSIX as the namespace reserved for variables meaningful to the shell itself and to POSIX-specified tools, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable implicitly overwrites any like-named environment variable.